Error when building android app with expo build
Build fails at gradlew with the following error.
Settings file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/apps/expo/android/settings.gradle' line: 4
 * What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] was not found in any of the following sources:
 * Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
 * Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
 * Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)`

 * reinstall node_modules
 * npx expo run:android fine
 * eas build failing

Build is run with managed workflow, so this settings file is automaticaly generated.

I am experiencing this same issue.

it seemed to be that GitHub was down.

Edit: While it coincided with Github going down, it looks like Expo devs pushed a change which broke. They have since reverted the change and I now have successful builds. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/31005#issuecomment-2290092592
Well, I had the same issue.
I did npx expo install --fix and now I have a different issue with: Unable to resolve "react-native/Libraries/Utilities/DevLoadingView" from "node_modules\@expo\metro-runtime\build\LoadingView.native.js"
Before that I tried:

rm -rf node_modules
yarn cache clean

I noticed while building today Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
Which is weird cause I've never really noticed that before on a regular yarn; npx expo prebuild --clean; npx expo run:android
Yesterday this project built fine. No dependencies have changed. I don't understand why it's broken today?
Just tried looking at Expo's repo to see if there's any issues related to this. https://github.com/expo/expo
No server is currently available to service your request.
Maybe related?

Exact same issue. iOS build is fine and builds/works as expected but Android faces the exact same issue.

https://www.githubstatus.com/
Github is down, I assume this is related

The Github outage caused this issue, but it's back up now. I had to run again expo prebuild --clean before expo run:android --device would work again.
